# What happened when constructing a variable of std::chrono::milliseconds from "LLONG_MAX seconds"?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

When constructing a variable of std::chrono::milliseconds from "LLONG_MAX seconds", the result `t_milli.count()` is **-1000**

```
auto t_max_seconds = std::chrono::seconds(LLONG_MAX);
auto t_milli = std::chrono::milliseconds(t_max_seconds);
```

As far as I can see, somehow "**-1**" came from "LLONG_MAX", and "**1000**" was the ratio.
(for "microseconds", the result is -1'000'000)

I wonder what happend here, an overflow or undefined-behavior?

Comment: I'm guessing undefined behavior with signed overflow. I don't see anything here http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration.cast that would say otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting signed overflow in the conversion from `seconds` to `milliseconds`.

On your machine both `seconds` and `milliseconds` are represented by signed 64 bit integers.  But to convert `seconds` to `milliseconds`, the library multiplies by 1000.

You are effectively doing this:

```
cout << LLONG_MAX*1000 << '\n';
```

which on my machine prints out:

```
-1000
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::chrono::seconds` is a `std::chrono::duration<>`, just like `std::chrono::milliseconds`. As you figured, `std::chrono::milliseconds` has a ratio of `std::milli`, which is `std::ratio<1,1000>`.

The Undefined Behavior here is that the representation of `std::chrono::seconds` may have as little as 35 bits. Only `std::chrono::nanoseconds` is required to have a (signed) 64 bit representation, and `LLONG_MAX` could even be higher than that.

Of course you can define `using seconds = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t>;`. There's nothing magical about `std::chrono::seconds`. Converting that to milliseconds has its own overflow risk, naturally.

I suspect you want `std::chrono::seconds::max()`.